# subset data.frame using POSIXct vector R

Tags: r

I'm trying to  extract a range of POSIXct dates from a data frame

with a sample data frame (data)...

```
library(lubridate)
start <- as.POSIXct('2016-10-08 20:00:00')  
time <- seq(start, start + days(1), by = "30 min")  
variable <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50), size = 49, replace = TRUE)  
data <- data.frame(time, variable)
```

I'm trying to create an indexed vector of date, using both a single date as well as a range.  I was going to initially subset the data frame, then extract the date column using the `$` operator (although I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it).

```
data_trim <- data[c('2016-10-08 20:00:00', '2016-10-08 22:0:00' %--% '2016-
10-09 13:00:00'),]
```

but the output is

```
     time variable
NA   <NA>       NA
NA.1 <NA>       NA
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: What libraries do you have loaded? I don't believe base R has a days() fn, and I'm getting an error.

Comment: Could you tell us the pack%--% ages you are using? Base has no days() nor the %--%  instruction...

Comment: sure, sorry I didn't include that - %--% is from lubridate.  I'm also using dplyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? You can replace `days(1)` with `60 * 60 * 24` (seconds * minutes * hours) if you don't need `lubridate` elsewhere.

**EDIT:** change to just extract the time vector.

```r
start <- as.POSIXct('2016-10-08 20:00:00')  
time <- seq(start, start + 60 * 60 * 24, by = "30 min")  
variable <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50), size = 49, replace = TRUE)  
data <- data.frame(time, variable)  

# If you wanted to keep the data.frame
# data_trim <- data[data$time == '2016-10-08 20:00:00' |
#                     (data$time >= '2016-10-08 22:0:00' &
#                        data$time <= '2016-10-09 13:00:00'), ]
# data_trim

# Otherwise just extract the time column into a vector
data$time[data$time == '2016-10-08 20:00:00' |
            (data$time >= '2016-10-08 22:0:00' &
               data$time <= '2016-10-09 13:00:00')]
#>  [1] "2016-10-08 20:00:00 NZDT" "2016-10-08 22:00:00 NZDT"
#>  [3] "2016-10-08 22:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-08 23:00:00 NZDT"
#>  [5] "2016-10-08 23:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 00:00:00 NZDT"
#>  [7] "2016-10-09 00:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 01:00:00 NZDT"
#>  [9] "2016-10-09 01:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 02:00:00 NZDT"
#> [11] "2016-10-09 02:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 03:00:00 NZDT"
#> [13] "2016-10-09 03:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 04:00:00 NZDT"
#> [15] "2016-10-09 04:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 05:00:00 NZDT"
#> [17] "2016-10-09 05:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 06:00:00 NZDT"
#> [19] "2016-10-09 06:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 07:00:00 NZDT"
#> [21] "2016-10-09 07:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 08:00:00 NZDT"
#> [23] "2016-10-09 08:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 09:00:00 NZDT"
#> [25] "2016-10-09 09:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 10:00:00 NZDT"
#> [27] "2016-10-09 10:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 11:00:00 NZDT"
#> [29] "2016-10-09 11:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 12:00:00 NZDT"
#> [31] "2016-10-09 12:30:00 NZDT" "2016-10-09 13:00:00 NZDT"
```

Comment: Thanks @hrabel - that should do it.  Yeah, I only used lubridate for illustrative purposes.